# Unable to Locate Android SDK Error in Appcelerator Studio

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio, appcelerator

I am facing below error while trying to compile android app using emulator in appcelerator studio.

Error:
`Unable to locate an Android SDK.`

If you have already downloaded and installed the Android SDK, you can tell Titanium where the Android SDK is located by running `titanium config android.sdkPath /path/to/android-sdk`, otherwise you can install it by running 'titanium setup android' or manually downloading from http://appcelerator.com/android-sdk.

I have provided sdk path as `/Users/Username/Library/android-sdk-macosx` in appcelerator studio.

Using titanium config `android.sdkPath /path/to/android-sdk` in terminal error `titanium: command not found`

I have installed Android studio on same Mac and I have provided same path in appcelerator studio

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is

```
appc ti config android.sdkPath /path/to/android-sdk
```

Or Else change manually using Appcelerator Studio:-

Click on Axway Appcelerator Studio-->Preferences-->Studio-->Platforms-->Android

and then select android-sdk folder. You are done.